# Calculate the flux of $F(x,y,z) = 3xy^2i + 3x^2yj +z^3$ on unit sphere?

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I can't seem to work out this problem:

Find the flux of $F(x,y,z) = 3xy^2i + 3x^2yj +z^3k$ out of the unit sphere centred at (0,0,0).

My attempt is as follows:

\begin{align*}
\iint_S  F \cdot dS &=
\iint_S [F(x,y,z) \cdot \hat{n}]dS\\
&\text{Since unit sphere:}\\
&=\iint_S [(3xy^2,3x^2y,z^3) \cdot (x,y,z)]dS && \\
&=\iint_S [3x^2y^2 + 3x^2y^2 + z^4 ]dS\\
&=\iint_S [6x^2y^2 + z^4 ] dS\\
&\text{ Converstion to spherical coordinates, with } r=1:\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} [(6(sin(\theta) cos(\phi))^2(sin(\theta) sin(\phi))^2 + cos^4(\theta)) \cdot sin(\theta)] d\theta d\phi\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} [(6sin^4(\theta)cos^2(\phi)sin^2(\phi) + cos^4(\theta)) \cdot sin(\theta)] d\theta d\phi\\
\end{align*}

At this point I can't work out how to simplify it further in order to do the integration. Is there a mistake somewhere or another way to proceed?

Comment: FWIW, the first two components are currently swapped in the title and body. (If the title version is correct, the first two terms of the dot product vanish in the integral.)

Comment: thx fixed the title

Comment: At this point you can proceed by recalling integrals of powers of trig functions over quarter periods, that you may have seen in calc II, e.g.,$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin\theta\, d\theta = 1,\quad \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2}\theta\, d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4},\quad \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{3}\theta\, d\theta = \frac{2}{3},$$etc., with the same values for power of cosine, and obvious extensions if you integrate over $[0, \pi]$ or $[0, 2\pi]$. The double-angle formula for sine may make life a bit easier.

Comment: Hmm I have not seen this before in Calc 2 or elsewhere. I feel like I must have made a mistake understanding the problem because all other problems like this we're given, all the terms boil down to something simple.

Comment: Integrals of powers of trig functions fall under the umbrella of "pretty simple". :) You must at least have learned how to calculate them at some point? That said, it's possible you're meant to use Gauss's theorem and integrate the divergence of $F$ over the ball; doing so does, in fact, avoid the bulk of the trig integration.